# problem with url of image after using (multer) to work with image in node.js

Tags: node.js, multer

i have a problem with url for images, this image url be like this:

```
http://192.168.43.106:3000/upload\\139585975-e-learning-concept-with-blurred-city-abstract-lights-background.jpg
```

the problem is here :

```
/upload\\
```

those (\) cause lot of problems , please how can i make the url is normal like this:

```
http://192.168.43.106:3000/upload/139585975-e-learning-concept-with-blurred-city-abstract-lights-background.jpg
```

i using this code to add middleware for image using (multer) in app.js: i think the problem is here with (diskStorage) and (destination)...

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb)=>{
   cb(null, 'upload');
    },

    filename: (req, file, cb)=>{
        cb(null, file.originalname);
         }
});
const filter = (req, file, cb)=>{
    if(file.mimetype == "image/jpg" || file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype == "image/png"){
        cb(null, true)
    }else{
        cb(null, false);
    }
}

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    filter: filter
});
app.post('/service' ,upload.single('file'));
app.use('/upload', express.static('upload'));
```

and this code to make get request to retrieve data including image url:

```
getAllServices : async (req, res)=>{
        try {
        const result = await SERVICES.find();
        res.json(
            {result : result.map(result =>{
                return {
                    id : result._id,
                    name : result.name,
                    file : 'http://192.168.43.106:3000:3000/'+result.file,
                    desc : result.desc,
                    price : result.price,
                    cat : result.cat,
                    url : 'http://192.168.43.106:3000:3000/service/'+result._id
                }
            })
            });
        }catch(err){result.json(err)}
        
        },
```

Comment: what value is in `file.originalname` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `file.originalname` which refers to the filesystem's path and you are most probably on Windows, this is actually the expected behaviour.

What you could do, is replacing the backslashes within `filename`:

```
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname.replace(/\\/g, "/");
}
```

Comment: thank you, but actually i try it, and nothing change!!

Comment: i solve the problem depend on your idea, but just the problem was from (path) in (req.file.path), when i insert new cat.... so just using replace function there when i make a post request..... thank you so much